# How to read a list saved in a file.txt as a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of [tokens, tags] saved in a text, and when I open the list in python it does not appear as a list. The list looks like this

```
[(u'porta', 'NN'); (u'scuola', 'NN'); (u'ragazzo', 'NN')]
```

and in python I open it in this way

```
   L = codecs.open('/directoryoflist/list', 'r', 'utf-8').read()
```

And when I make

```
for i L:
   print i:
     #it does not give me the item in the list
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Why you dont response to your older question ! i think i answer to a question of you like this last day !!!

Comment: Writing the representation of a list to a text file is not a good idea if you expect to read it back as a list. Use JSON instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> import re
>>> import ast
>>> a="[(u'porta', 'NN'); (u'scuola', 'NN'); (u'ragazzo', 'NN')]"
>>> my_list = ast.literal_eval(re.sub(';',',',a))
>>> my_list
[(u'porta', 'NN'), (u'scuola', 'NN'), (u'ragazzo', 'NN')]
>>> type(my_list)
<type 'list'>
```

Comment: @AhmadFawi anytime :)